# update several records using update_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm trying to update few things in my user for it's role and its plan_id .. I've came up with something dirty in my console but everytime I'm trying to use update_all similar way I'm getting no where. I think I'm missing something.. here's my original console way;

```
expired_subscription_user_ids = Subscription.where("expiry_date < ?", Time.now.beginning_of_day).pluck(:user_id)
User.where(:id => cancelled_subscription).each do |user|
   user.role = 'cancelled'
   user.plan_id = 'cancelled'
   user.save
end
```

Here's the same thing but using update all that's not working out for me.

```
User.where(:id => cancelled_subscription).each do |user|
   user.update_all(:role => 'subscriber', :plan_id => 'subscriber')
end
```

So pretty much all users with cancelled_subscription will have their role and plan_id chanced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the `.update_all` method on an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, like this:

```
scope = User.where(:id => cancelled_subscription)
scope.update_all(:role => 'subscriber', :plan_id => 'subscriber')
```

Documentation: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all

---

An interesting comment in the documentation, from "openface":

> Note that ActiveRecord **will not update the timestamp fields** (updated_at/updated_on) when using update_all().